# How to convert PHP Nested Array into JQuery Array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I Am Trying to Convert an Nested PHP Array into JQuery Array but it is Throwing an Error.

**This is a PHP Array i.e. output as print_r**

```
Array( 
[867] => Array ( [id] => 867 [title] => ATM [permalinks] => atm 
[parent_id] => 1 [status] => 0 [sort] => 2 [icon_class] => [image] => 
[page_strip_id] => 0 [meta_title] => [meta_keyword] => [meta_description] => 
[show_on_home] => 0 [tot_listing] => 0 ) 
[344] => Array ( [id] => 344 [title] => Grocery [permalinks] => grocery 
[parent_id] => 10 [status] => 0 [sort] => 0 [icon_class] => icofont icofont- 
gift [image] => [page_strip_id] => 0 [meta_title] => [meta_keyword] => 
[meta_description] => [show_on_home] => 0 [tot_listing] => 0 ))
```

**Jquery Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var child_cat_id=JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($child_cat_id);?>');
    console.log(child_cat_id);
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

How Can i Convert it and use it as same as PHP array

Comment: `var child_cat_id = <?php echo json_encode($child_cat_id);?>;`

Comment: you don't need to parse it, just assign it to a variable as it is.

Comment: @u_mulder  I did and it works but somewhere in this variable ' i.e. (apostrophe) exist so the rest data Throwing an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" for ' and The Rest Data Truncated, How Can I Sanitize it as and in Array

Comment: `json_encode` escapes all symbols. So, your problem is somewhere else. Open generated html/js and see what you have  there.

Comment: paste the actual JSON (as seen in the screenshot and "view source" of your page) in an online JSON validator to see where it has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON can have single quotes, which in JSON format are not escaped, but would end the string literal that you make in JavaScript. Also, backslashes would not have the extra escaping that a JavaScript string literal needs.

It is easier to not parse the JSON at all and assume that the JSON is JavaScript compatible, which it is when produced by PHP (i.e., no issues with line-break characters as PHP escapes those by default):

```
var child_cat_id=<?php echo json_encode($child_cat_id);?>;
```

There is just one other thing to take into consideration: `json_encode` will return `false` in case of an error during the encoding process. For instance, when there is non-UTF8 data to be encoded, you'll get that result. `echo` will output nothing in this case, which will make the above solution invalid JavaScript (i.e. `=;`). You can work around this in JavaScript in several ways, for instance, as follows:

```
var child_cat_id=["error", <?php echo json_encode($child_cat_id);?>].pop();
```

So `child_cat` will be "error" whenever PHP cannot encode the data as JSON.